# IllegalStateException: PWC3990: getWriter() has already been called for this response

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jfreechart

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3990: getWriter() has already been called for this response
```

How to solve this error? I run a simple servlet code to display the bar graph.

Comment: unless you show us some relevant code, how do you think we can guess how to fix your problem?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot call **both** `getOutputStream()` and `getWriter()` on the *same* response. Keep in mind that JSP *implicitly* uses `getWriter()`.

Comment: but how to use getoutputstream in jfreecharts at the same time how to disply the string using getwriter???

Comment: In theory, you need to write the string to `getOutputStream()` instead. You can use `OutputStreamWriter` for this. Since I don't use JFreeChart, I only don't know if it's allowed by JFreeChart to mix the response like that.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure that the request is not being redirected to current servlet from some place else. If it is, then there is a high probability that one of `getOutputStream()` or `getWriter()` has already been called on it.