# How to use pngRenderingService.render in TagLib to get image tag instead of <img>

Tags: grails, png, rendering

i use Taglib `<g:mediaitem bean="${item}" />` to render media tag accordiong to type of item

```
def item=attrs['bean']    
if(item?.type=='img')
    {
      out << '<img src="'+item?.src+'" />'
    }else if(item?.type=='audio') {
       out<< '<audio src="'+item?.src+'" />'
    }
      //..........
```

When i use this tag to render pdf , i get the error of end-tag , i search on solution and i found `renderPng` and `rendering:inLinePng` , . I cannot use it in TagLib .

My Question is : how can i use rendering png plugin in taglib to not have error when rendering image in gsp that will be rendered to pdf . 
if i can use pngRenderingService.render, what are the arguments that should be passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to convert the image in bytes and then use rendering plugin tag lib do render the image e.g.,

```
 File imageFile = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("images/imageName.png"))
 out << rendering.inlinePng(bytes: imageFile.bytes)
```

**EDIT....................................................................**

I am working on a project in which I am also using the rendering plugin to download the content in PDF format and above code I posted is working fine my side.

Bellow is my complete tag to render image in PDF.

```
class ComJftTagLib {
    static final namespace = 'jft'

    def image = { attrs ->
        String dir = attrs.remove('dir')
        String file = attrs.remove('file')
        File imageFile = new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/${dir}/${file}"))
        out << rendering.inlineGif(bytes: imageFile.bytes)
    }
}
```

My image is placed in images/ folder.

**EDIT....................................................................**

```
out << '<img src="data:'
out << 'image/png'
out << ';base64,'
out << new String(new Base64().encode(imageFile.bytes), "UTF-8")
out << '" />'
```

Comment: Did you mean: renderingService.inlinePng instead of rendering.inlinePng , because i try : rendering.inlinePng , renderingService.inlinePng and pngRenderingService.inlinePng . and it is in vain

Comment: Please try above taglib I posted and test it on a sample image.

Comment: i tested it , and i get the folllowing error  : getWriter() has already been called for this response...at grails.plugin.rendering.RenderingService.writeToResponse(RenderingService.groovy:82)

Comment: You cannot call both getOutputStream() and getWriter() on the same response. Keep in mind that JSP implicitly uses getWriter(). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312309/illegalstateexception-pwc3990-getwriter-has-already-been-called-for-this-res

Comment: One more try, instead of using rendering tag lib directly, open its tag lib and copy code that render image and use it in your tag lib. See my edited answer.